# couldnot connect to localhost:8069

Tags: localhost, odoo

I am running my openerp at my localhost:8069 . It was working fine till tomorrow but today the page is not loading and it says " could not connect to localhost:8069". Please give me any suggestion because I had made quite changes and am a bit worried about this issue.
Hopes for suggestion

Comment: working till tommorrow?

Comment: Please paste the changes you have made

Answer (score 1):

I dont know this is the best answer or not. But i had tried this before.
...
All you need is go to the Windows, then find and click ". Next, search your OpenERP service (if you are using Odoo, you'll find "PostgreSQL_For_Odoo - PostgreSQL Server 9.3), then go to "Restart the service".